# Excel solver function equivalent in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am looking optimisation method in Matlab, where I can apply constraints on a parameter which is a function of another constrained parameter.

The error function to minimise is:

errfun = Ltrue - Lref(x1,x2) - Lemm(x1,x2,x3)

The optimisation parameters are x1,x2,x3 with their respective lower and upper bounds. Ltrue, Lref, Lemm are vectors of size 8. Ltrue is the vector containging the constant "true" values which are already defined. I am currently using the Matlab function "lsqnonlin".

However, the problem is that I also require a constraint on the value of Lemm(8).

In excel solver, this is easy to do since I can just add a specific constraint to the cell containing Lemm(8). I can't find any equivalent in any of the Matlab optimsation functions though. Is there any function I am not aware of which can do this, or some workaround to make use of existing Matlab functions?

Comment: Maybe check out https://uk.mathworks.com/products/optimization.html?

Comment: Yup, I've tried looking at every function in the toolbox but can't find anything which can apply a constraint on a parameter which is a variable in another constrained paramter. Thanks for making the suggestion though.